# Setting color to cardview android

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-color

```
String playerteamcolorstr=playerteamcolorlist.get(i);
viewHolder.soldedlinearlayout.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(playerteamcolorstr+""));
```

I am getting the hex color code string  from json url and want to set the color on Card view. It is showing the error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color at
>   android.graphics.Color.parse

Comment: Your color code in malformed . Debug your code and check if its a valid color code or not . Do not miss `#` as prefix in color code .

Comment: I am getting color in hex code . I have also checked log

Comment: what color code you are using ? show

Comment: What is playerteamcolorstr value? Have you checked ? Does it have "#" in front?

Comment: Try to get color code in Proper Format. If it does not contain # in start add it manually.